# Is it safe to swap the neutral wire between the supply and load side?

Tags: wiring, switch

I have a double-pole cooker switch I wanted to replace. But careless me forgot to mark the neutrals when disconnecting the old switch.

The socket has 4 wires, 2 red and 2 black. One red & black pair is the supply (of which I've marked the live wire), the other pair goes to my AC unit.

Is it safe if I just connect the 2 neutral wires to whichever side?

Picture below illustrates my situation. Except there's no Earth wire in my case.
Can I swap where the neutral wire goes on the switch? (Yellow circles)

Thanks in advanced!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already said they come into the box in pairs/cables.   And you said you marked the supply hot.

The supply neutral should be in the same pair/cable as the supply hot.

So there you go.

Generally switches are direction-agnostic, *unless* the labeling or instructions says otherwise, as would surely be the case for a smart switch.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear about it. By pair I only meant there were an even number of wires, and I deduced that 2 came from the supply and 2 goes to the load. They were not bound together in any way.

I tested it and it worked so either I connected them correctly or I didn't but the direction doesn't matter. Either way thanks for your input!